# How can compute Bandwidth for Caches SRAM with benchmarks simulation?

Tags: gem5, cacti

please , which equation can be used to find the total bandwidth for cache L2 SRAM with Benchmark running by gem5 simulation ,
we have BW(read+write ) for SRAM from Destiny tools , but how can compute the BW with running benchmarks ?

Comment: How do you define the cache bandwidth? Max bandwidth for an all-hit access (this is likely a SimObject input parameter? Or the bandwidth for a given experiment? If for a given experiment, how does it differ from DRAM bandwidth? Have you looked through the stats to see if anything of interest?